# CoffeeCup Web Form Builder regEx issue

Tags: regex

I'm creating a web form using a coffeecup web form builder and I have added a regular expression field. I need the user to be able to enter only numbers, whole or with a decimal point. I have tried various regular expressions including:

```
/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1-2})?$/

/\G\d+(?:\.\d{1,3})?/
```

But I'm still not able to enter decimal point values in the field.

I have already searched the web and tried many examples, I've even tried the RegexMagic and none of the solutions seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with ASP.Net's Web Forms technology? If not, you should remove the "webforms" tag from your post.

Comment: @JimMSDN removed the tag